# Triangle of smallest area whose three sides are the $x$-axis, the line $y = x$, and the point $(2,1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, triangles, area

Find the triangle of smallest area in the half-plane to the right of the
y-axis whose three sides are respectively segments of the $x$-axis, the diagonal
$y = x$ , and a line through $(2, 1)$. [This is from MIT's Single Variable Calculus Course].

This is my attempt at the answer:

I'm making the assumption that one vertex of the triangle is at the origin. I'm not sure this is right since it says one side is a segment of the $x$-axis. Then, the points $(2,1), (a, a)$, and $(b,0)$ must lie on the line with the point $(2,1)$. And the points $(0,0), (a,a)$, and $(b,0)$ are the vertices of the triangle.

Trying to find an equation using the points, I have:
$$y - a = \frac{1-a}{2-a}(x-a)$$

Then $$0 = \frac{1-a}{2-a}(x-a) + a$$  and$$ x= b = \frac{a}{a-1}$$

Using Heron's formula for the area of the triangle,

$$A = \frac{1}{2}\left|ab\right| = \frac{a^2}{2-2a}$$ assuming 2a < 2 (I found the same value for a, when I assumed 2a > 2)

$$A'= \frac{4a - 2a^2}{(2-2a)^2}$$

Setting $$A'= \frac{4a - 2a^2}{(2-2a)^2} = 0$$  a = 0 and a = 2

Plugging in a = 0 into the original formula for A gives 0. Plugging in a = 2, gives $$A = \left|\frac{2^2}{2-2(2)}\right|\ = 2$$

I would please like to know if I am on the right track or if I have made faulty assumptions.

Thank you!

Comment: Your triangle has points (0,0), (2,2) and (2,0). Doesn't that give area = 2?

Comment: Yes, you're right c.z. I was multiplying the area by another factor of $$\frac{1}{2} $$. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Everything else looks like it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of proof is right, though the proof is not complete to the last detail. Some annotations...

> I'm making the assumption that one vertex of the triangle is at the origin. I'm not sure this is right since it says one side is a segment of the x-axis.

It *is* right because you are given that two sides lie on the $x$-axis and the diagonal $y=x$ respectively. Any two sides of a triangle have a vertex in common, and in this case that vertex can only be the intersection of the two lines, which is the origin.

> Then $\;\;\cdots$ $$b = \frac{a}{a-1}$$

Note that the triangle must be "*in the half-plane to the right of the y-axis*", which means $a \gt 0$ and $b \gt 0$ (neither can be $0\,$, otherwise the triangle would be degenerate). Then $b=\frac{a}{a-1} \implies a \gt 1$.

> Using Heron's formula for the area of the triangle,
>
> $$A = \frac{1}{2}\left|ab\right| = \frac{a^2}{2-2a}$$ assuming 2a < 2 (I found the same value for a, when I assumed 2a > 2)

- [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula) refers to something else. I don't know that the "*half of base times height*" formula has its own brand name.
- Since $a\gt1$ per previous observation, the area is in fact $A=\cfrac{a^2}{2a-2}\,$.

> $$A'= \frac{4a - 2a^2}{(2-2a)^2}$$

Alternative without calculus:

$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2-1+1}{a-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+1+\frac{1}{a-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(2 + (a-1)+\frac{1}{(a-1)}\right) \ge \frac{1}{2}(2+2)=2
$$

The latter inequality follows from $x + \frac{1}{x} \ge 2$ for $\forall x \gt 0$ with equality iff $x=1$. Therefore the minimum area is $2\,$, and is attained when $a-1=1 \iff a=2\,$.

Comment: Thank you so much, dxiv! This gave me a lot more insight into the problem.